# What is the difference between these display screens?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, laptop-display, led

Please check these 3 products:

1. http://www.snapdeal.com/product/CompaqPres/89388
2. http://www.snapdeal.com/product/lenovo-ideapad-30015isk-notebook-80q700uein/639467071061
3. http://www.snapdeal.com/product/lenovo-ideapad-30015isk-notebook-80q700ugin/631252118447

If you see the specifications, you'll notice the display screens are different. In 1st, it is: **BrightView HD LED-Backlit**. In 2nd, it is: **HD TN GL(Slim)** and in the 3rd one, it is: **Full HD WLED Backlit TN Glare Slim Display**.

Ignore the more resolution of 3rd laptop. I just want the difference between these 3 screens and I want to know which gives better look of videos, games or movies.

Answer (score 3):

1) **BrighView HD LED-Backlit** display is a glossy screen. It has advantages such as clearer images, wide viewing angles, high contrast, vivid colors and reduced eye fatigue.

2) **HD TN GL(Slim)** is TN matrix that has dim colors, but it better for gaming, because it has a smaller response time.

3) **Full HD WLED Backlit TN Glare Slim Display** is a glossy screen that has TN matrix with WLED backlit. It consumes less energy, but it displays less colors.

In conclusion, first display better for movies, second and third better for games, but they have a little worse picture.

Comment: In my current laptop, I've BrightView HD LED Backlit display. Everything is fine except the color intensity is low. What I mean is that when I see an image in my laptop, it is seems less colorful but if I see the same image in most of other new laptops of my friends, it shows better color intensity.